# Вызов функции в aiogram

Tags: python, функции, aiogram, бот

Есть вот такая функция:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='Получить_список_вопросов') # запрос вопроса из бд
async def get_qwestions_list(message: types.Message):
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('data.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    qwestion = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM qwestions').fetchall()
    result = ""
    for qwestion_list in qwestion:
        result += f" {qwestion_list}\n"
        result = clear_text(result)
    await message.answer(result)
```

Как дальше я могу ее вызвать? Какие аргументы указать не могу понять get_qwestions_list(???)

Comment: Вам не нужно вызывать эту функцию. Эту функцию вызовет aiogram, когда боту придет соответствующая команда.

Comment: Ладно), тогда так): ```@dp.message_handler() # запрос вопроса из бд
async def get_qwestions_list(message: types.Message):
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('data.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    qwestion = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM qwestions').fetchall()
    result = ""
    for qwestion_list in qwestion:
        result += f" {qwestion_list}\n"
        result = clear_text(result)
    await message.answer(result)```

Comment: Что "тогда так"?

Answer (score 0):

Пишите вашему боту в телеграм: `/Получить_список_вопросов` и команда срабатывает.Знак _ можно заменить на обычный пробел(НЕ НУЖНО СЕБЯ МУЧИТЬ), тогда вызывать можно:

```
/Получить список вопросов
```